# Why I can't omit properties from already omitted type?

Tags: typescript

I have simple case of omitting properties from another already omitted type:

```js
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;

interface A {
  x: string;
  y: number;
}

interface B extends A {
  z: Date;
  w: boolean;
}

type OmitA<T extends A> = Omit<T, 'x'>;
type OmitB<T extends B> = Omit<OmitA<T>, 'z'>;
```

The type OmitA has only property 'y' as expected. But the OmitB type throws error:

`Type '"z"' does not satisfy the constraint 'Exclude<keyof T, "x">'. ts(2344)`

Is this a bug or is there a problem with this code ?

**Update 1**

It looks like it works if I change the OmitB type to:

```js
type OmitB<T extends B> = Omit<OmitA<T & B>, 'z'>;
```

which looks unnecessary to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation of the way you define `Omit`, `K` must be a `keyof T`. But since `T` is an unresolved type parameter typescript can't figure out if `Omit<T, 'x'>` will really contain `z` (more like it does not bother). There are ways to get around this, but the simplest solution would be to use the definition of `Omit` that will be added soon in typescript 3.5 ([PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30552)) which does not require `K` to `extend keyof T`

```
type Omit<T, K> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>; // no constraint as in the new Omit in 3.5

interface A {
    x: string;
    y: number;
}

interface B extends A {
    z: Date;
    w: boolean;
}

type OmitA<T extends A> = Omit<T, 'x'>;
type OmitB<T extends B> = Omit<OmitA<T>, 'z'>; // works fine now
```